# how to solve the Class cast exception in HibernateTemplate's findByCriteria()?

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc, classcastexception

**This is the method of Dao class that is throwing Exception:**

> I did not used any Integer here. Even the phone number property is
>   also a String as it can contain +,() Symbols sometimes.

```
public List<StudentDetails> retriveStudents( String studentFirstName, String studentLastName,String studentEmail, String studentPhoneNum) {
        logger.info("AddStudentDao retriveStudents():- START");
        List<StudentDetails> nonTerminatedStudentsList = null;
        //List<UserLocationMapping> userLocationMappings = null;
        Set<Integer> studentIdSet = new HashSet<Integer>();

        try {
            DetachedCriteria objmCriteria = DetachedCriteria.forClass(StudentDetails.class);
            //objmCriteria.createAlias("studentDetails", "UserDetails");
            objmCriteria.add(Restrictions.ne("loginId", Constants.SUPER_ADMIN));
            if (!Utilities.IsEmpty(studentFirstName)) {
                objmCriteria.add(Restrictions.like("firstName", "%" + studentFirstName + "%"));
            }
            if (!Utilities.IsEmpty(studentLastName)) {
                objmCriteria.add(Restrictions.like("lastName", "%" + studentLastName + "%"));
            }
            if (!Utilities.IsEmpty(studentEmail)) {
                objmCriteria.add(Restrictions.like("email", "%" + studentEmail + "%"));
            }
             if (!Utilities.IsEmpty((studentPhoneNum))) {
                objmCriteria.add(Restrictions.like("phoneNumber", "%" + studentPhoneNum + "%"));
            }

            nonTerminatedStudentsList = hibernateTemplate.findByCriteria(objmCriteria);//*****EXCEPTION RAISING*****(Line number 216)

            if (studentIdSet != null && studentIdSet.size() > 0) {
                nonTerminatedStudentsList = getStudents(studentIdSet);
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error(" AddStudentDao retriveUsers :- ", e);
        }
        logger.info("AddStudentDao retriveUsers():- END");
        return nonTerminatedStudentsList;
    }
```

> This is supposed to return a List of StudentDetails objects but the
>   method used in this scenario is raising an Exception. Hope somebody
>   can help me.

**and the exception is shown like this:**

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.lang.String
    at org.hibernate.type.StringType.toString(StringType.java:67)
    at org.hibernate.type.NullableType.nullSafeToString(NullableType.java:117)
    at org.hibernate.type.NullableType.nullSafeSet(NullableType.java:158)
    at org.hibernate.type.NullableType.nullSafeSet(NullableType.java:136)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.bindPositionalParameters(Loader.java:1732)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.bindParameterValues(Loader.java:1703)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.prepareQueryStatement(Loader.java:1593)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:696)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:259)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2232)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2129)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2124)
    at org.hibernate.loader.criteria.CriteriaLoader.list(CriteriaLoader.java:118)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1597)
    at org.hibernate.impl.CriteriaImpl.list(CriteriaImpl.java:306)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate$36.doInHibernate(HibernateTemplate.java:1056)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate$36.doInHibernate(HibernateTemplate.java:1)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.doExecute(HibernateTemplate.java:406)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.executeWithNativeSession(HibernateTemplate.java:374)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.findByCriteria(HibernateTemplate.java:1046)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.findByCriteria(HibernateTemplate.java:1039)
    at com.pss.admin.dao.student.AddStudentDao.retriveStudents(AddStudentDao.java:216)
    at com.pss.admin.dao.student.AddStudentDao$$FastClassByCGLIB$$41df7ff.invoke(<generated>)
    at net.sf.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:191)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(Cglib2AopProxy.java:618)
    at com.pss.admin.dao.student.AddStudentDao$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$25e36467_2.retriveStudents(<generated>)
    at com.pss.admin.bo.student.SaveStudentService.retriveStudents(SaveStudentService.java:91)
    at com.pss.admin.controller.student.StudentController.retriveStudents(StudentController.java:98)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:213)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:126)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:96)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:617)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:578)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:80)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:923)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:852)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:789)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1041)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:603)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: can you post your `StudentDetails` class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry guys.. My bad.
the constant in the first Restriction is an integer.
 Thank you.